# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "saber a cuerno quemado"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Estaba leyendo el otro día [un artículo](http://www.elconfidencial.com/deportes/futbol/2017-01-07/gerard-pique-arbitros-lopetegui-seleccion-espanola_1312950/) (muy malo, de prensa rosa deportiva) cuando me topé con una expresión que no había oído nunca antes:

> En el pasado, y no lejano, **diferentes manifestaciones** de Gerard Piqué **sentaron a cuerno quemado** en el interior del vestuario del Real Madrid. Sobre todo en el clan de los internacionales españoles, que torcieron el gesto más de una vez, al sentirse atacados por su compañero en la Selección española. El sonado episodio de Kevin Roldán y otras afirmaciones públicas del buen futbolista del Barça generaron tensión cuando el proceso de acercamiento y normalización en el interior de la Roja marchaba sin excesivos sobresaltos.

Por contexto entendí que básicamente se refería a que dichas declaraciones sentaron mal a cierta gente.

Sin embargo, me llamó la atención y la RAE me reveló su explicación:

> [**cuerno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BakkB8M)
>
> **saber algo a cuerno quemado**
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Hacer desagradable impresión en el ánimo. Su reprensión me supo a cuerno quemado.

La web del ministerio de Educación de España menciona en [Curiosidades sobre las biomoléculas](http://recursos.cnice.mec.es/biologia/bachillerato/segundo/biologia/ud01/02_01_04_06.html):

> - El olor especial que se dice a cuerno quemado y que se produce precisamente al quemar formaciones epidérmicas (cuernos, pezuñas, lana, pelo, uñas), se debe al contenido de azufre que presenta la proteína queratina, principal componente de estas estructuras.

¿Es por tanto este el motivo de hablar de *oler a cuerno quemado*? ¿Cuál es su origen? Lo digo porque no concibo demasiada gente a mi alrededor que haya olido alguna vez un cuerno que se está quemando, por lo que me resulta curioso cómo consiguieron popularizarlo aquellos que sí han vivido esta experiencia.

---

Como *bonus track*, indicar que la RAE también me descubrió:

> **oler a cuerno quemado**
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Hacer sospechar que existen intenciones ocultas.

Al parecer es equivalente a la expresión *oler a chamusquina*, ambas con un origen similar explicado en [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "me huele a chamusquina"?](http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/icual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-me-huele-a-chamusquina):

> La locución tiene su origen en las hogueras inquisitoriales en las que ardían los libros y escritos sospechosos de herejía acompañados a veces de sus autores o impresores. Así, la frase se aplicó en principio a las obras y escritores que podían acabar en la hoguera de la Inquisición. Una versión del dicho es esta otra: "me sabe a cuerno quemado". En su origen, significó estar en la sospecha de que alguien va a ser llevado al fuego inquisitorial por cornudo.

Comment: La ocurrencia más antigua del CORDE es de 1843, mientras que Ngram me descubre [una de 1728](https://books.google.es/books?id=6-yWLyHTReEC&pg=PA31&dq=%22cuerno+quemado%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPjY2_7dDRAhVJChoKHaEBCUAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22cuerno%20quemado%22&f=false): "El Ciervo tiene odio con las culebras, y ellas con èl, en tanto que del olor de su cuerno quemado, huyen las culebras, y se vàn à otro lugar."

Comment: Todavía me acuerdo de unas prácticas de química en COU (años ha...) en la que el profesor, tras quemar un poco de azufre, preguntó "A qué huele esto?". Olía a **pelo quemando**, pero alguien dijo "A **cuerno** quemado". Nos reímos todos porque no hizo gracia la expresión, pero el profesor nos mandó callar a todos porque esa respuesta era más que correcta. Y sí, estaba explicando la presencia de azufre en pelo, uñas, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El significado de la expresión es literal. Un cuerno quemándose tiene un olor parecido a cuando se quema el pelo o el vello del brazo; un olor que, al menos para la mayoría de la gente, resulta bastante desagradable (adaptación evolutiva, seguramente).

Dices: *No concibo demasiada gente a mi alrededor que haya olido alguna vez un cuerno que se está quemando*. No hoy en día, desde luego. Pero hace 100, 50 o incluso 30 años era bastante más habitual que la [matanza](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=matanza) y preparación de los animales para ser cocinados y consumidos se hiciera en los entornos familiares o comunales; con lo cual es de esperar que el olor a "cuerno quemado" fuese reconocido por casi todo el mundo (cuando se estuviese asando un carnero, o chamuscando la piel del cerdo, o similar).