# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "me sabe a cacho"?

Tags: coloquialismos, colombia

En Colombia es común usar la expresión "me sabe a cacho" cuando una situación causa disgusto o es incómoda. Por ejemplo, si una canción ha estado de moda mucho tiempo y empieza a ser molesta se puede decir:

> Esa canción ya me sabe a cacho.

Otro ejemplo:

> [Me sabe a cacho](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/MAM-1958336) que los colombianos nos sumerjamos en unas disquisiciones tan absurdas y nos enzarzemos en unos debates sin sentido, en vez de analizar problemas de verdad importantes para el país, como la corrupción, la inequidad social o el desempleo, por decir algo.

¿Por qué hacer la analogía de una situación molesta con comer algo que ni siquiera se asociaría con comer? Se entendería si se hablara de un alimento desagradable, pero ni siquiera un animal se podría comer un cacho. ¿Se usa o entiende la expresión en otros lugares?

Nota: Como se pregunta en los comentarios, aclaro que el significado que le doy a la palabra cacho es el de cuerno. Con esto, la pregunta es similar a [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión “saber a cuerno quemado”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-la-expresi%C3%B3n-saber-a-cuerno-quemado). Allí se explica que el olor de un cuerno quemado es desagradable, pero no sé si esa explicación aplica para la expresión por la que pregunto acá porque en ella no se menciona que sea quemado ni tampoco habla del olor sino del sabor. Es decir, si alguien quema un cuerno y hay gente cerca pues lo oleran así no quieran. Pero ¿quién trataría de comerse un cuerno?

Comment: ¿Qué es un cacho para ti? Yo entiendo *cacho* como *trozo* y aunque no tiene sabor en si mismo se pueden comen cachos de comida.

Comment: Estoy viendo que en el _Diccionario de americanismos_, ["cacho" significa "cuerno"](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cacho) en muchos países de Hispanoamérica, Colombia incluida. ¿Podría entonces tu pregunta ser similar [a esta otra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19412/12637)?

Comment: @blonfu y Charlie, efectivamente yo entiendo cacho como cuerno. De manera que es similar a la pregunta que Charlie enlaza, aunque es curioso porque la respuesta que se da allí está orientada al **olor** de un cuerno y especifica que **quemado**.

Comment: Es un poco como la expresión "sabe a rayos", nadie come rayos. Al menos un cuerno lo puedes chupar y ver a qué sabe.

Comment: No conocía esa expresión. Han de saber raro jejeje

Comment: Hace muuuuchos años cuando era pequeño y esa frase se usaba mucho le pregunté a mi papá el porque decía así y me dijo que por lo del olor a cuerno quemado. Parece que hace tiempo era muy frecuente hacer objetos de cuerno (peinillas, mangos para navajas, etc) y parte del proceso incluía el uso del fuego y el olor era tan penetrante que se sentía en la boca. Además, al menos en los pueblos antioqueños, nadie dice cuerno sino cacho.

Comment: Yo pensaba que venía de "cacho de mierda" que es lo mismo que "pedazo de mierda."  Pero yo no uso "cacho", sólo uso "cachito" (y no de mierda).

Answer (score 1):

La expresión "me sabe a *cosa desagradable*" puede no referiste literalmente al gusto que se siente en la boca al comer algo, sino a la impresión desagradable que causa.

Los dichos y refranes tienden a abreviarse con el uso y el paso del tiempo, a veces conservando el sentido original y otras veces variándolo por completo.

En este caso el original era ["saber a cuerno quemado"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-la-expresi%C3%B3n-saber-a-cuerno-quemado?noredirect=1&lq=1) y luego quedó en "saber a cuerno".