# Origen de la expresión "pedazo/cacho de..."

Tags: modismos, historia, españa, sustantivos

Según el diccionario, la palabra *pedazo* tiene una acepción coloquial que conocemos en España:

> **[pedazo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SIH8YqC)**
>
> Del lat. vulg. *pitaccĭum*, metát. del lat. *pittacĭum* 'trozo de
>   cuero', 'colgajo', y este del gr. *πιττάκιον pittákion*.
>
> 1. m. Parte o porción de algo separada del todo.
> 2. m. Cualquier parte de un todo físico o moral.
> 3. m. coloq. U., seguido por la preposición *de*, para reforzar el significado del adjetivo o del sustantivo al que antecede.

Esta tercera acepción es la que nos permite decir cosas como "¡vaya pedazo de coche que tienes!" o "ese tío es un pedazo de bruto". Y me pregunto: ¿cómo es posible que una parte de un todo se llegara a usar para intensificar la cualidad del adjetivo o sustantivo que sigue?

Recientemente he visto un anuncio de una marca de chocolate cuyo eslogan es "pedazo de sabor". Y la verdad es que me cuadraba que la expresión tuviera un origen publicitario, algo así como "un pedazo del chocolate X es un pedazo de sabor". En todo caso, esto no es más que una elucubración.

Así pues, ¿cuál es el origen de la expresión "pedazo de..." como refuerzo de significado?

Bonus: ¿Se usa en Hispanoamérica?

> *TERESA: [...] (A MALIBRÁN) ¿Alcanzó usted a Varessi?
>
>   MALIBRÁN: Le oí en Italia. ¡Qué pedazo de barítono!*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Realidad. Novela en cinco jornadas", 1889 (España).

---

Nótese que esta pregunta aplica también a la palabra *cacho*:

> **[cacho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6Xvqvzr)**
>
> Del lat. vulg. **caccŭlus*, y este del lat. *caccăbus* 'olla'; cf. gall.
>   *cacho* 'vasija rota, pedazo quebrado de una vasija' y port. *caco*
>   'cacharro, pedazo de loza'.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Pedazo o trozo de algo.
> 2. m. coloq. U., generalmente seguido por la preposición *de*, para reforzar el significado del adjetivo o del sustantivo al que antecede.

---

> *No hay duda que así, varonilmente desaliñado, húmeda la piel de transpiración ligera, terciada la escopeta al hombro, era un cacho de buen mozo el marqués [...].*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "Los pazos de Ulloa", 1886 (España).

Comment: Bonus: _Pedazo_ si se usa en Colombia de la misma forma pero _cacho_ aunque significa "pedazo" no la usamos de la misma manera. Cuando sale la luna y solo se ve un pedacito pequeño decimos ["cachito de luna"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bzNIw6j7yQ)" o cuando comes una galleta alguien te pude decir "¿me das un cachito?"

Answer (score 4):

Me inclino a pensar que es un nuevo caso de ironía / antífrasis, al igual que en el caso de "[menudo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16995/17253)".

En ambos casos, se trata de una palabra que literalmente debería significar una versión más pequeña, pero que sin embargo se utiliza con el significado opuesto, como aumentativo.

Comment: Puse el enlace directamente al término "menudo" pero si prefieres como estaba antes, hazle un rollback, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Solo puedo hablar del bonus, que si se usa también en América Latina.  Yo diría que sí, pero no sé si el uso es tan extensivo como pintas para España.

En **México** he oído, por ejemplo, **pedazo, cacho** o **pedazo** de **mierda, melón**, etc.  Pueden ser expresiones de cariño o disgusto.  Incluso a veces la expresión grosera se utiliza para expresar intimidad y hasta cierto cariño sarcástico.

Hay [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23121/9385) acerca de una expresión usada en **Colombia**:

> ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión “me sabe a cacho”?  [Es una expresión se se usa] cuando una situación causa disgusto o es incómoda.

Quizás se relaciona.

Comment: No creo que esto se pueda vincular con la otra pregunta relacionada con Colombia. En este contexto pedazo/cacho significan "una parte de" mientras que en la expresión "sabe a cacho" cacho es sinónimo de "cuerno". O sea, nada que ver.

Comment: @DGaleano - Ah, bueno.  Se me ocurrió que podría ser un eufemismo para *sabe a cacho de mierda*.

Comment: Jajajaja..... no es así, pero es una excelente idea. LMAO